# No GatewayAddresses when looping through NetworkInterfaces on Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm  trying to scan the local IP address of a mobile device to ping all other devices in a network and discover local IP addresses.
In the first step I'm retrieving the GatewayAddress of the local NetworkInterface like this:

```
foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
{
    if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
    {
        foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation d in f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
        {
            ip = d.Address.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly fine on iOS, however on Android the `GatewayAdresses` have a count of `0`. As far as my research goes there has been bugs with `NetworkInterface`s in Xamarin but they seem to be all fixed by now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the code to get the ipv6 and ipv4.

```
 foreach (NetworkInterface f in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
        {
            if (f.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            {
                //foreach (GatewayIPAddressInformation d in f.GetIPProperties().GatewayAddresses)
                //{
                //    var ip = d.Address.ToString();
                //}
                IPAddress ipv6Address = f.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[0].Address; //This will give ipv6 address of certain adapter
                IPAddress ipv4Address = f.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses[1].Address; //This will give ipv4 address of certain adapter

            }
        }
```